# python gzip "unexpected end of file" when writing a data stream

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I'm writing (or more precisely, appending) a real-time data stream to an instance of python's gzip module. If the program that's writing the stream crashes, and relaunches, I would like the stream to automatically be appended to the original file. Unfortunately this fails in practice, as I get an "unexpected end of file" error that corresponds to the exact point at which the original program crashed.

What's the underlying approach for handing this situation, as I can't imagine this should be a hard problem. My approach is outlined below:

```
f = gzip.GzipFile( 'filename_json.txt.gz' ), mode='at', compresslevel=9)
while(something_is_true):
    f.write(stream['message'] + '\n')
f.close()
```

This runs continuously, but if the program crashes (or gets killed), the end-of-file operator never gets appended, and the gzip file becomes corrupt. In which case, any data appended after that point becomes unreadable.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a try: finally: clause to ensure the file is always closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
with gzip.open('filename_json.txt.gz', mode='at', compresslevel=9) as f:
    while something_is_true:
        f.write(stream['message'] + '\n')
```

(This works for me on python 2.7.6)

But if that for some reason isn't working, you can do it the old fashioned way:

```
try:
    f = gzip.open('filename_json.txt.gz', mode='at', compresslevel=9)
    while something_is_true:
        f.write(stream['message'] + '\n')
finally:
    f.close()
```

Note that the error will still propagate with this code unless you catch the error. But the file will be closed.

Comment: Does this function if the process is killed?

Comment: `gzip.open` and `gzip.GzipFile` work with `with` for me on python 2.7.6.

Comment: @AsksAnyway, no, this only "cures" the case where a Python exception occurs, not the case where the program is killed e.g., by a terminating signal or power loss.

Comment: How should we handle the case where the process is killed?

Comment: If you're killing it with e.g. ctrl-c that will send a sigint and raise a python exception. If you're killing it -9 or cutting power then of course it's not going to work.

Comment: what happens when using "supervisorctl stop"?

Comment: @vgoklani My guess would be sigterm, and this appears to be the default in their [documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html).